# How to convert a Panasonic .RW2 raw image file to a DNG file?

Tags: linux, conversion, imagemagick

I have just purchased a Panasonic TZ80 camera. It can produce [RW2](https://fileinfo.com/extension/rw2) (aka: RAW) files. How can I convert these to [DNG](https://fileinfo.com/extension/dng) in Linux? I’d like to be able to do this on the command line without a graphical interface.

It doesn’t look like ImageMagick is capable of doing this. I have tried to compile some packages on GitHub, but I have run into problems with compilation. Apps like [Dcraw](https://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) can convert to TIFF or PPM, but I can’t see how I can convert any of these to DNG.

I need to have DNG files to use with Lightroom. I’m aware that I can do this with Windows, but I’d like to create a Linux script to automatically handle this.

Comment: This seems to be a very convoluted workflow. Can't a recent version of LR handle your RW2? Or didn't you get an adequate RAW-processing application with the camera? Otherwise you can hop to [pixls.us](https://discuss.pixls.us/) and see which of the various demosaicing apps can support your RW2 files (at least RawTherapee supports the ancestors of your TZ60, so it could be very easy to add).

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way of converting RW2 files to DNG files, but it's not a command line tool. In the program, Digikam, you can find a DNG converter. I installed kipi-plugins package (I'm on Linux Mint), and I was able to convert a simple RW2 file to a DNG file. I think it can also do batch conversions.

[image]
[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately no - it doesn't help - the machine is used predominantly as a server and doesn't have any graphical desktop.  I've read that Digikam did this.  Presumably there's code in there that does the conversion . . .

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Sorry, the closest this will get is PPM, not DNG.

[Terry Ross](https://www.flickr.com/people/qnr/) explained how to do this with [ufraw](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/) and ufraw-batch, likely available in your favorite package repository:

```
ufraw-batch --wb=camera --out-type=ppm *.rw2
```

[Read the whole post](https://www.flickr.com/groups/793920@N24/discuss/72157613460778780/) for how to use an additional tool to bring over exif data if needed.

Note: This worked for me but left red and blue pixels in many photographs where black pixels should be— the raw format must have felt that the values it was getting were out of bounds.  I'm sure there's a way to figure out how to fix this in the program's graphical user interface and then apply the same transitions in the batch command line, but i didn't try.